# Which Android SDK supports ticker?

Tags: android

How to implement ticker in Android application. I can't find Ticker
in Android SDK.

Comment: Ticker? Android SDK does not include such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/29d827c0218eb1bb?pli=1

> - What can i do with it?
>
> Not much! Email the author!? Find a
>   new tutorial!?

Sorry.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer 1000 times. @sangita, there is NO Ticker class built in to Android. And, IMO, after taking a look at that tutorial, I would suggest you find a better resource for learning.

Answer (score 0):

If by Ticker you mean something like the [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), then there is something available through the SDK.

Comment: This link http://java.dzone.com/articles/google-android-tutorial?page=0,3 shows ticker.